# Scala: Using HashMap with a default value

Tags: oop, data-structures, scala, hashmap

I have a mutable HashMap and would like to use it like a default-dictionary. The obvious method appears to be to use getOrElse and provide the default value each time as a second value. However this seems a little inelegant in my use case since the default value doesn't change.

```
var x = HashMap(1 -> "b", 2 -> "a", 3 -> "c")

println(x.getOrElse(4, "_")
println(x.getOrElse(5, "_"))
// And so on...
println(x.getOrElse(10, "_"))
```

Is there any way to create a HashMap (or similar class) such that attempting to access undefined keys returns a default value set on the creation of the HashMap? I notice that HashMap.default is just set to throw an exception but I wonder if this can be changed...

Comment: To anyone who stumbles upon this question, missingfaktor's post correctly states that 

"Scala 2.9.1. mutable.Map comes with a withDefaultValue method"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
import collection.mutable.HashMap
val x = new HashMap[Int,String]()  { override def default(key:Int) = "-" }
x += (1 -> "b", 2 -> "a", 3 -> "c")
```

Then:

```
scala> x(1)
res7: String = b

scala> x(2)
res8: String = a

scala> x(3)
res9: String = c

scala> x(4)
res10: String = -
```

Comment: +1. Wonder why `mutable.HashMap` doesn't provide a `withDefaultValue` method like `immutable.HashMap`.

Comment: It's horrible syntax, but it does the trick. Maybe the lack of withDefaultValue for mutable HashMaps should be reported as a bug?

Comment: There is a "!!! todo: move to general maps?" comment in the neighboring `withDefault` in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html. So may be this is not too much of a stretch. The scala-user mailing list is probably a good place to inquire about this and see if a bug should be reported.

Comment: @PythonPower an enhancement ticket was submitted http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3829.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it! It's really nice to see Scala being so actively improved.

Answer (score 72):

Wow, I happened to visit this thread exactly one year after I posted my last answer here. :-)

Scala 2.9.1. `mutable.Map` comes with a `withDefaultValue` method. REPL session:

```
scala> import collection.mutable
import collection.mutable

scala> mutable.Map[Int, String]().withDefaultValue("")
res18: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map()

scala> res18(3)
res19: String = ""
```

Comment: I'm concerned about the performance for this - does mutable.Map use HashMaps? How's its performance?

Comment: `WithDefault` only overrides the `default` method (thus only affects `apply`) and returns the default value when the key is not found. Everything else is sent to the underlying `Map`

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val x = HashMap(1 -> "b", 2 -> "a", 3 -> "c").withDefaultValue("-")
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map((1,b), (2,a), (3,c))

scala> x(3)
res0: java.lang.String = c

scala> x(5)
res1: java.lang.String = -
```

**EDIT:**

For `mutable.HashMap`, you could do the following:

```
scala> import collection.mutable
import collection.mutable

scala> val x = new mutable.HashMap[Int, String] {
     |   override def apply(key: Int) = super.get(key) getOrElse "-"
     | }
x: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map()

scala> x += (1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c")
res9: x.type = Map((2,b), (1,a), (3,c))

scala> x(2)
res10: String = b

scala> x(4)
res11: String = -
```

There might be a better way to do this. Wait for others to respond.

Comment: @PythonPower: You had not specified it in your original question that you were using `mutable.HashMap`. I don't know how to do it with `mutable.HashMap`. I'll have to look into the API.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't specify -- I've edited my question to make it clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more a java guy... but if `getOrElse` is not final, why don't you just extend `HasMap` and provide something like this:

```
override def getOrElse(k: Int, default: String) = {
  return super.getOrElse(k,"_")
}
```

Note: syntax is probably screwed up but hopefully you'll get the point

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible to extend HashMap. In which case it'd probably be easier to change the HashMap.default method to return what I want. The constructor could take the default value and the HashMap.default method would just return that. I'm hoping there's an easier method, however.

Comment: We don't do this bc it is more complicated than `getOrElse` - it has less flexibility, is unnecessarily verbose, and if you *must* do this, is a strong indication you should be using some high level abstraction, like monoids.