# How to work with an Option[Set[A]] in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given a toy example like:

```
val myMap = Map("a" -> Set(10, 20))
val myVal = 20
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?:

```
val myKey = "a" // imagine this comes from a loop
myMap.get(myKey) match {
  case Some(set) => set.contains(myVal)
  case None => false
}
```

I guess I could do this, but it doesn't seem idiomatic:

```
myMap.contains(myKey) && 
  selectedGsnsAtOdo(myKey).contains(myVal)
```

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652683/filtering-on-scala-optionset)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will achieve the same result as the `match` expression:

```
myMap.get(myKey).exists(_.contains(myVal))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
myMap.getOrElse(myKey, Set.empty).contains(myVal)
```

Possibly even use a [map with the empty set as its default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3648870/1048572) straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Just to pile on :)

```
myMap.get(myKey).fold(false)(_(myVal))
```